# Google Sheets custom function to change a value in multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I have multiple spreadsheets on google sheets - they all have identical formats, and they keep track of very similar information.  I'd like to be able to change info over all the documents - for instance if column 4 says "A1" of any of the rows in any of the documents I'd like to be able to easily change column 7 of all of those rows in each of the documents.

I'm new to javascript so the custom formulas have been challenging. I currently have a master sheet that uses a query to combine all of the sheets so they are visible/ sortable together,  but because they are ported in a query items are not editable in the master sheet. There is a limited enough amount of information that if I could edit the mastersheet, I could just sort the info and edit manually.  So a solution to that is another option.  I'm open to any kind of fix.

Thank you

Comment: You tagged google-sheet-api but I don't see where you use it? The solution to your problem will most likely need it, but you don't seem to have tried code yet. You might wanna look at their documentation first.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample sheet so that it is easier to visualise your issue and easier to provide a helpful solution? So, you basically want to be able to change the multiple cells in different sheets with the same value, am I right? What are you intending to use to achieve this? Apps Script or Sheets API or Google formulas?